# Not all text being written to file using file_put_contents

Tags: php

I have output from `shell_exec` which looks like this:

```
0134d690 W ContainerSetContentPacket::getName() const                  
00d06f64 W ResourcePackDataInfoPacket::getId() const                   
00d06f80 W ResourcePackDataInfoPacket::write(BinaryStream&) const      
00d0713c W ResourcePackDataInfoPacket::handle(NetworkIdentifier const&, 
NetEventCallback&) const                                              
00d06f68 W ResourcePackDataInfoPacket::getName() const                 
00bf510c W StructureBlockUpdatePacket::getId() const                   
00bf5128 W StructureBlockUpdatePacket::write(BinaryStream&) const      
00bf52f0 W StructureBlockUpdatePacket::handle(NetworkIdentifier const&, 
NetEventCallback&) const
```

And i'm trying to write the method to a file with the class name. If you don't know what i'm talking about, heres an example:

```
ClassName::function()
ClassName::function2()
```

I would like to write `function()` and `function2()` to a file named ClassName.txt. Now currently my code creates all the files and adds only one function (`getName()`) or in the above example `function()` but not `function2()`

Now this is a problem. When i echo the `$method` variable below right before writing to file it displays all functions but it only writes one to file.

PHP code:

```php
<?php

    $out = trim(shell_exec("nm -DC *.so | grep 'Packet::'"));
    $out = explode("\n", $out);
    $out = array_filter($out, "trim"); 
    foreach($out as $line) {
        $line = explode(' ', $line, 2);
        $class = substr($line[1], 0, strpos($line[1], "::"));
    
    if(strpos($class, "std") === false and strpos($class, "void") === false
        and strpos($class, "vtable") === false) {
        
        $title = array_filter(explode("\n", substr($class, 2)), "trim");
    }
    
    foreach($title as $name) {
        $function = substr($line[1], strpos($line[1], "::"));
        $function = substr($function, 0, strpos($function, ")"));

        if(strpos($function, "_") === false and strpos($function, "<") === false 
            and strpos($function, "+") === false
            and strpos($function, "vtable") === false
            and strpos($function, "void") === false) {
        
            $method = str_replace("W", "", "void $function);");
            $method = str_replace("T", "", $method);
            $method = str_replace("::", "", $method);
        }
        file_put_contents("stuff/$name.txt", $method . PHP_EOL);    
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you're calling `file_put_contents`, the file will be overwritten. So you're writing to the file, then overwriting the file each time your loop iterates.

You can use `FILE_APPEND` as the third argument to `file_put_contents` to tell it to append to the file instead, but in this case it probably makes more sense to first `fopen()`, then `fwrite()` for each iteration in the loop, then call `fclose()` at the end. That way the file is only opened once, instead of for each iteration of the loop.

```
file_put_contents("stuff/" . $name . ".txt", $method . PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND);
```